# Why array of complex numbers is declared row-wise in fftw?

Tags: c, arrays, fftw

The [fftw manual](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3.pdf) states that ([Page 4](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Complex-One_002dDimensional-DFTs.html))

> The data is an array of type fftw_complex, which is by default a `double[2]` composed of the real (`in[i][0]`) and imaginary (`in[i][1]`) parts of a complex number.

For doing FFT of a time series of `n` samples, the size of the matrix becomes `n` rows and 2 columns. If we wish to do element-by-element manipulation, isn't accessing `in[i][0]` for different values of `i` slow for large values of `n` since C stores 2D arrays in row-major format?

Comment: Aren't memory look-ups pretty much constant time throughout address space?

Comment: i am a beginner and didn't understand what u said :(

Comment: my question relates to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148575/why-is-it-worse-to-initialize-a-two-dimensional-array-like-this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real and imaginary part are stored consecutively in memory (assuming little endian lay out where byte 0 of R0 is at the smallest address) :

```
In-1,Rn-1..|I1,R1|I0,R0
```

That means that it's possible to copy an element i into place accessing the same cacheline (usually 64byte today), as both real & imaginary are adjacent.  If you stored the 2D array in the Fortan order and wanted to assign to one element, then you immediately access memory on 2 different cachelines, as they are stored N*sizeof double locations apart in memory - [Row & COlumn Major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order)

Now if your processing was just operating on the real parts in one thread and the imaginary seperately in another, for some reason, then yes it would be more efficient to store them in Column major order, or even as seperate parallel arrays.  In general though, data is stored close together because it is used together.

All arrays in C are really single dimensional byte arrays, unless you store an array of pointers to arrays, usually done with things like strings with varying lengths.

Sometimes in matrix calculations, it's actually faster to first transpose one array, because of the rules of matrix multiplication, it's complex but if you want the real nitty gritty details search for Ulrich Dreppers article at LWN.net about memory which shows an example that benefits from this technique (section 5 IIRC).

Very often Scientific numberic libraries have worked in Column major order, because Fortran compatability was more important than using the array in a natural way.  Most languages prefer Row major, as it's generally more desirable, when you store fixed length strings in a table for instance.