# C# multidimensional array (2D) more than enough memory assigned

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

So I am assigning `int[,] matrix = new int[1, 2];`. But while debugging I see that my matrix has [0,0] [0,1].(slots) Why is that? I have 2 slots for values? Shouldn't it be only 1? (Don't tell me I have to use a one dimensional array, this is only an example). If I want to declare a 3 by 2 matrix for example (only 3 possible rows) [0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2] how should I do it?

Comment: You should have [0,0] and [0,1] as valid indices. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @itsme86 yea just edited

Comment: Why are you expecting only 1? Even a one-dimensional array like `new int[2]` gives you 2 slots (0 and 1).

Comment: What is 1 x 2 ?

Comment: @itsme86 the two slots come from the "1" right?

Comment: The two slots come from the 2 in the 2nd dimension. If you had `new int[1,1]` you would end up with a single usable slot [0,0].

Comment: @itsme86 I'm such an ... I was wondering what I was mistaking... so the first dimension is basically the columns and the second is the rows right? Please reply the question so I can vote

Comment: @john I update my anwser so now its anwser your update question

Comment: Here's [more reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567329/multidimensional-array-vs)

Comment: @itsme86 I am more used to working with jagged arrays... So which is the column and which is the row in the multidimensional array?

Comment: You can do it whichever way you want, but for performance reasons (CPU cache hits), you want to iterate over higher dimensions more rapidly than lower dimensions. For instance, if you're iterating over rows and for each row you iterate over the columns, you'll want the rows to be the first dimension and the columns the second. If you have `int[3, 3]`, you want to access them [0,0] [0,1] [0,2] [1,0] [1,1], etc. Hopefully that makes sense. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11148619/1141432) really nails it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Array start always with Index 0

So

[0,0] = Dimension 1 Value 1
[0,1] = Dimension 1 Value 2

Edit:

If you want 3 Values in 1 Dimension you have to do

```
int [,] matrix = new int [1,3];
```

I Hope it helps you?

Comment: The syntax to declare a 1×3 matrix is `int [,] matrix = new int [1,3];`.

Comment: @DourHighArch yes sorry my Mistake

Comment: @Darem which is the row and which is the column?

Comment: @john if you want to see it like this in the Example the 1 = row and 3 = columns

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are confusing somehow.

Apparently a `1 x 2 matrix` has 2 slots.

If you only need 1 slot, it's `1 x 1 matrix`

Example:

[image]

Hope it helps